# Mac + xcode 6.4 - header include path

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, macos

So, I have an Xcode project that contains sources which include headers from external library (static one)

The include is done in common way:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <jsapi.h>
```

The third line causes compiler error: `'jsapi.h' file not found`

E.g.: `Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'jsapi.h' file not found`

Now I got that I should add include folder into the project settings. So I opened the projects and into `Search Paths` category under `Header Search Paths` I've added `/usr/local/include/` where the headers really are. Still same error. I tried copying them under `/Users/.../include/` and pointing there - still same error.

So I tried going through SO and people suggested using `User Header Search Paths`, did that - still same error.

Now I know this will be something really dumb, but why Xcode does not search those paths on default (assuming that `/` means root folder - as for some reason my C headers are under `./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/`). I could try copying those header files in there, but well ... that just makes more harm than good.

Comment: Where is `jsapi.h` located? Also, it should be `#include "jsapi.h"` not `#include <jsapi.h>`

Comment: Why don't you go to the compile "tab" and look at the generated command line? You will see whether Xcode has correctly generated the -I options.  (it always does for me). Doing mdfind jsapi.h  at the command line to confirm where the header file is located could help as well.

Comment: #I'L'I nope it shouldn't (I'm migrating the project from Linux system and you use < and > braces for library based includes and just add -I... include folder path). Unless Mac has different standards for these.

Comment: #Laurent Michel - For `mdfind jsapi.h` the result is correct (it is where I'm searching for it). I'm having minor problems orienting inside Xcode - could you give me hint or two navigating into compile "tab"

Comment: I just realised that the `-I...` is not even added into the compiler flags. How is that even possible?!

Comment: The main window is split in 3 panes (left / center / right). The top of the left pane has a row of buttons [Projects, Hierarchical, Search, Errors, Tests,Debug, Breakpoint, Build]. The last button of that row select "build view" for the middle pane. Once you see a build, pick a line that compiles a .m file. On the far _right_ there is a small icon that looks like a page of text. Click on it. It will show the build command for that file. [Wish I could figure out how to put screenshots in Stack Overflow comments ;-)].

Comment: The setting you are looking for is "Header Search Paths" It is under the "Search Path" section of your settings. I use it regularly, so I know it is supposed to work. Keep in mind that Xcode applies the settings hierarchically. If the setting is overriden "deeper" in the tree, the setting you give at the root will be ignored. I've been burned by this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show....

The "build tab" is called "Report Navigator". I circled it...

[image]

Then you can see the icon to the far right of:
[image]

Click that button and you will see the text of the build command in its full glory.

Finally, in the option, you can see below that I have the setting defined for a 3rd party library:

[image]

You can even see that I used the "User Header Search Paths" in this case. BTW, I also added the library search path (just above).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this seems close to what I need, but what do you mean "in the option"? Where did you find this "Search Paths" dropdown?